# Is it possible to get every trophy in SSB for 3DS without the Trophy Shop?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

I've been trying to get every trophy in Super Smash Bros. for 3DS without resorting to buying them from the Trophy Shop. I've played flawless Trophy Rush games and various other modes over 400 times now (not exaggerating) and I've still not gotten any new trophies. I have about 530 trophies right now, but still need around 70 more to beat the 600 trophy challenge.

I know there are more trophies to collect since they appear on the Trophy Shop, but I only want to start getting them through there until I'm certain there's no other way to get them.

Comment: I would bet that there's a non-insignificant amount of trophies that cannot drop randomly until bought at least once from the shop, but I don't think we currently have solid proof (hence why this is not an answer).

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot get every trophy without buying any from the shop.

There are eight trophies that are only available from the trophy shop. These trophies represent the fighters that are included as costume swaps of other fighters:

- Alph
- Larry
- Morton
- Wendy
- Iggy
- Roy
- Lemmy
- Ludwig

These trophies cannot initially appear in the shop and will only appear after completing Classic mode with the character who they are a costume swap of (Olimar for Alph and Bowser Jr. for the Koopalings).

All other trophies can be earned by other means.

Mario Wiki has a great list that includes unlock criteria for all 685 non-DLC trophies as well as the growing list of DLC trophies [**here**](http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_trophies_in_Super_Smash_Bros._for_Nintendo_3DS).

Comment: Is this true for the Wii U version as well?

Comment: @BJMyers There are a lot of trophies that can only be purchased from the trophy shop on the Wii U version, including alternate costumes for all non-DLC characters, which require you to beat classic mode as each character before they will appear in the shop. The Wii U list of trophies and how to acquire them can be found here: http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_trophies_in_Super_Smash_Bros._for_Wii_U